# "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ConstraintLayout_Layout_layoutDescription" when I initialize project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Okay, I create a completely new project with the default template and this is what happens:
[image: Failed to in]

What is happening?
Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the xml file code in which you have a ConstraintLayout?

Comment: I posted it on my main question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay...
The result was not as satisfying, but it worked. In the designer, I went to the layoutDiscription field and entered some random number, and then I clicked on the hammer icon and it just works! Now even if I create a new project, it still works. Thanks for all the other questions you guys have answered.

Answer (score 7):

Just rebuild the project and it will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

an old version can fix this problem
like
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000, built on August 27, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.instant.shutdown=false, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.intellij.marketplace, Dart, org.jetbrains.kotlin, io.flutter, com.ruiyu.ruiyu, cn.yiiguxing.plugin.translate, izhangzhihao.rainbow.brackets, org.intellij.plugins.markdown

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).